# Using client-server to move object on screen

Tags: java, client-server, paint

So I'm trying to use a client-server with a keyListener. When the messages "#left" or "#right" are sent to the server, it should update the graphical object and shift it to the left by calling the map.repaint() method. Instead, it shifts the object once and then no further responses happen. Posted below is the code. Can someone offer a solution?

// the server

```
@Override
    protected void handleMessageFromClient(Object msg, ConnectionToClient client) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(msg instanceof String)
        {
            String message = msg.toString();

            if(message.equals("#connect"))
            {
                String error = "Already connected";
                Matcher match = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(matches.get(i).contains(client))
                    {
                        match = matches.get(i);
                        try {
                            client.sendToClient(error);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            System.err.println("Could not send #connect error message");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(match == null)
                {
                    Matcher matcher = new Matcher(this,client);
                    matches.add(matcher);
                }
            }

            if(message.equals("#left"))
            {
                action("left",client);
            }

            if(message.equals("#right"))
            {
                action("right",client);
            }

            if(message.equals("#jump"))
            {
                action("jump",client);
            }

            if(message.startsWith("#shoot"))
            {
                String error = "please connect";
                Matcher match = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(matches.get(i).contains(client))
                    {
                        match = matches.get(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(match == null)
                {
                    try {
                        client.sendToClient(error);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.err.println("Could not send #left error message");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    match.moveLeft(client);
                }
            }
            if(message.contains("?"))
                            try {
                                client.sendToClient(msg);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
        }
    if (msg instanceof Integer)
                try {
                    client.sendToClient(msg);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Message not sent. Turning off.");
                }


private void action(String errorm, ConnectionToClient client)
    {

            String error = "please connect";
            Matcher match = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
            {
                if(matches.get(i).contains(client))
                {
                    match = matches.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(match == null)
            {
                try {
                    client.sendToClient(error);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.err.println("Could not send #" + errorm + " error message");
                }
            }else
            {
                if(errorm.equals("left"))
                {
                match.moveLeft(client);
                }else if(errorm.equals("right"))
                    {
                        match.moveRight(client);
                    }
                                else if(errorm.equals("jump"))
                        {
                            match.updateJump(client);
                        }
            }
    }

//the matcher class which controls graphics
public void moveLeft(ConnectionToClient client)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
        {
            if(players[i].getId() == client.getId())
            {
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    synchronized(this)
                    {
                    map.updateFirstPlayer(map.getx1Rec1() - 5, map.gety1Rec1(), map.getx2Rec1(), map.gety2Rec1());
                    map.repaint();
                    map.updateUI();
                    }
                }
                    if(i == 1)
                    {
                        synchronized(this)
                        {
                        map.updateSecondPlayer(map.getx1Rec2() - 5, map.gety1Rec2(), map.getx2Rec2(), map.gety2Rec2());
                        map.repaint();
                        map.updateUI();
                        }
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            client.sendToClient(map);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Could not update left");
        }
    }

    public void moveRight(ConnectionToClient client)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
        {
            if(players[i].getId() == client.getId())
            {
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    synchronized(this)
                    {
                    map.updateFirstPlayer(map.getx1Rec1() + 5, map.gety1Rec1(), map.getx2Rec1(), map.gety2Rec1());
                    map.repaint();
                    map.updateUI();
                    }
                }
                    if(i == 1)
                    {
                        synchronized(this)
                        {
                        map.updateSecondPlayer(map.getx1Rec2() + 5, map.gety1Rec2(), map.getx2Rec2(), map.gety2Rec2());
                        map.repaint();
                        map.updateUI();
                        }
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            client.sendToClient(map);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Could not update right");
        }
    }

    public void updateJump(ConnectionToClient client)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
        {
            if(players[i].getId() == client.getId())
            {
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    synchronized(this)
                    {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j+=5)
                    {
                    map.updateFirstPlayer(map.getx1Rec1() , map.gety1Rec1() + j, map.getx2Rec1(), map.gety2Rec1());
                    /*try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                    map.repaint();
                    }
                    }
                }
                    if(i == 1)
                    {
                        synchronized(this)
                        {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j+=5)
                        {
                        map.updateSecondPlayer(map.getx1Rec2(), map.gety1Rec2() + j, map.getx2Rec2(), map.gety2Rec2());
                        /*try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }*/
                        map.repaint();
                        map.updateUI();
                        }
                        }
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            client.sendToClient(map);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Could not return jump");
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is `handleMessageFromClient` method being called? Moreover, is the issue with the GUI or with only one message coming through?

Comment: handleMessageFromClient is called from the run()method of the server. And I'm not totally sure.

Comment: Assuming the issue is with the GUI, try to call `revalidate()` before any `repaint()`